# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi, 1)}{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{y^2+y-2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have this problem here:

Show that the limit does not exist.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi, 1)}{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{y^2+y-2}}$$

This first part I'm asking just to make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong.

I taked two ways to the point: $y = \frac{1}{\pi}x$ and $y=\frac{1}{\pi^2}x^2$

So, we'll have:
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{(\frac{1}{\pi}x)^2+\frac{1}{\pi}x-2}}$$

And:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{(\frac{1}{\pi^2}x^2)^2+\frac{1}{\pi^2}x^2-2}}$$

Using this, we get a $\frac{0}{0}$ situation were we use l'Hopital's rule.

And them, we get two vallues: $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

There's any error in that idea?

The second question is: The exercise said that it was possible to show switching to Polar coordenates too, but I tried and it seemed really hard. Can someone show me or guide me how to show that this way?

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with your approach, but isn't the function just plain not defined for any $x$ when $y=1$? That alone means that the limit can't exist.

Comment: Sorry, but now I'm a bit confuse. Was not that the whole point of the limit? To try to understand the function where it is not defined, using the points around?

Comment: I'm not saying just that the function isn't defined at $(\pi,1)$; I'm saying it's not defined at $(x,1)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see the difference... Yeah, it makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @Greg Martin : $g(x,y)=x\frac{|y|}{y}$ . $g$ is not defined at $(x,0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. But $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} g(x,y)$ exists.

Comment: @perroquet: I disagree, for the reason you mentioned. Suppose $f(x)=x$ when $x$ is irrational and $f(x)$ is undefined when $x$ is rational. Do you count $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = 0$ as true? I don't, for the same reason.

Comment: @Greg Martin: In your example, I count $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$ as true.

Comment: @perroquet: okay, sounds like we're working from different definitions of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to let
variables go to zero.

If $y = 1+z$ and
$x=\pi+w$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi, 1)}{\dfrac{1+\cos(x)}{y^2+y-2}}
&=\lim_{(w, z)\to(0, 0)}{\dfrac{1+\cos(\pi+w)}{(1+z)^2+(1+z)-2}}\\
&=\lim_{(w, z)\to(0, 0)}{\dfrac{1-\cos(w)}{1+2z+z^2+1+z-2}}\\
&=\lim_{(w, z)\to(0, 0)}{\dfrac{1-(1-w^2/2)}{z^2+3z}}\\
&=\lim_{(w, z)\to(0, 0)}{\dfrac{w^2}{6z}}\\
\end{array}
$

By letting
$w$ and $z$
approach zero in various,
you can make this
take any value.

For example,
if $z = aw^2$,
this is
$\dfrac1{6a}$;
if $z = w$ this is $0$;
and if
$z = w^3$
this is $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**

Your idea is correct but your solution is false.

You wrote that

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi}{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{(\frac{1}{\pi}x)^2+\frac{1}{\pi}x-2}}=\dfrac{\pi}{3} \ \ \  $  and $\ \ \ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pi}{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{(\frac{1}{\pi^2}x^2)^2+\frac{1}{\pi^2}x^2-2}}=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$

But these two limits are equal to 0.

You must choose another paths ...

**Second question:**

I don't think it's a good idea to use polar coordinates in this exercise.